# No power in one room (circuit), breaker not tripping

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I have one room with no electricity, flipping the breaker has no effect, and using a multi-meter to test the breaker, says there's 120 volts coming out, so its not the electrical panel. I used a receptacle tester, and I was getting a hot/ground reverse and hot/neutral on one socket, so I replaced all the outlets, found in two locations there was a white connected to black, so I connected those to the correct colors. After that I kept getting hot/ground reversed so I disconnected the wiring to an old ceiling fan and it's switch. This corrected the hot/ground reversed and I'am getting a correct reading on all sockets, but I still have fluctuating voltage when testing hot to neutral of 1-10 volts on the outlets. When testing hot to ground however, I get a full 120 volts.

Comment: This smells like an open neutral somewhere -- what voltage do you measure from neutral to ground?

Comment: fluctuates .5-1 volts. I've disconnected the circuit as upstream as possible, but I'm left with an outlet and a triple switch that still have incoming hot, so I assume that there may be a junction box in the wall that feeds to those 2 locations.

Comment: Hrm....there's probably still stuff you have yet to find, yes...

Answer (score 2):

Your test shows you have hot coming from the breaker (hot to ground 120 volts) but you are loosing it on the neutral side. I would start at the breaker box again only this time looking at (volt meter test) the neutral wire. If it's good go to the first junction box and test there and so on.